# SELECT statement takes hours to execute

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to run this `SELECT` statement but I takes hours to execute. I have also created index on those tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    j.Name AS State,
    l.DisplayName AS ServiceCenter,
    l.JurisdictionID,
    e.LocationID,
    ConvictionStateID AS RegionId,
    FeeGroupID,
    e.VehicleID ,
    ServiceDate,
    evd.EventlogID,
    v.ClientID,
    e.EventLogServiceID,
    evd.EventlogDetailID,
    EvtDT AS EventDate,
    EvtVal AS EventValue,
    evd.EventLogCodeID,
    UPPER(SerialNumber) AS SerialNumber,
    UPPER(RelayNum) AS RelayNumber,
    edp.FileName,
    GPSLatitude
FROM
    [MM\PLUSREPORT5].lsa_plus_jur_nico.dbo.EventLogDetail evd
INNER JOIN 
    [MM\PLUSREPORT5].lsa_plus_jur_nico.dbo.EventLog e ON evd.EventlogID = e.EventlogID
INNER JOIN 
    [MM\PLUSREPORT5].lsa_plus_jur_nico.dbo.Vehicle v ON e.VehicleID = v.VehicleID
INNER JOIN 
    [MM\PLUSREPORT5].lsa_plus_jur_nico.dbo.Client c ON v.ClientID = c.ClientID
INNER JOIN 
    [MM\PLUSREPORT5].lsa_plus_base.dbo.Location l ON e.LocationID = l.LocationID
INNER JOIN 
    [MM\PLUSREPORT5].lsa_plus_base.dbo.Jurisdiction j ON l.JurisdictionID = j.JurisdictionID
LEFT JOIN 
    [MM\PLUSREPORT5].lsa_plus_jur_nico.dbo.EventLogDetailPhoto edp ON evd.EventLogDetailId = edp.EventLogDetailId
```

[Excution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp7rt.png) , also embedded below.

[image: Excution plan]

Comment: Please post the **table structures** and the **index creation scripts**

Comment: I'm joining seven tables together how can I post table structure

Comment: Please can you help rewriting the  query to avoid hash match  imaging I have Index on all of the key columns

Comment: Your indexes play a big factor in performance. We need to see the execution plan to understand where your query is suffering. Maybe it's just millions of records. We can't know without the execution plan. We also can't guess your indexes or what the "key columns" are. Post the plan...

Comment: Yes I just added execution plan

Comment: Any sort warnings or hash warnings? Any blocking? What are the wait types? Doesn't look like that should take hours. It scans each table once. Also any scalar UDFs involved? (Eg as computed columns?)

Comment: Looking at execution plan it does uses hash match and the data is approximately 300M rows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're not getting any Parallelism and Sorts are popping-up.

Check if your Indexes are configured to DESC order.

A limitation of Backward Scans of indexes is that they cannot go Parallel.

Also try and remove the DISTINCT if possible, this can add the same limitations.